# matplotlib in vs studio code can't update plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, plot

I'm using matplotlib in vs studio code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
for i in [1,2,3]:
      plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6))
      plt.cla()
      env.render_all()
      plt.show()
      time.sleep(5)
```

It will pop out an individual window besides the vs studio code window ,and only show the first round plot of the looping ,and then the process will be stuck ,until I manually close the individual plot window ,the process will go on and the second loop plot will pop out.

I have tired:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
for i in [1,2,3]:
      plt.close() 
      plt.close(2)
      plt.close(plot1)
      plt.close('all')
      plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6))
      plt.cla()
      env.render_all()
      plt.show()
      time.sleep(5)
```

And none of this works for me ,I want to keep showing the old plot until 5 seconds later the new plot comes and automatically update the older plot to new plot.

Any friend can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Can this work if you use method `plt.ioff()`?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
for i in [1,2,3]:
      plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6))
      plt.cla()
      env.render_all()
      plt.pause(0.01)
      plt.ioff()
      
plt.show()
```